# Is the expectation value of an operator obtained by canonical quantisation always the classical value?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, commutator, quantization, poisson-brackets

I understand that generally, for some Hermitian operator $\hat{A}$, the classically measured value of a system is given by
\begin{align}
\langle \hat{A}\rangle=\langle\psi| \hat{A}|\psi\rangle
\end{align}
The conditions for canonical quantisation of the classical theory given in textbooks are

1. Replace the canonically conjugate variables with operators.
   \begin{align*}
       (q_{i},p_{i})\rightarrow(\hat{Q}_{i},\hat{P}_{i})
   \end{align*}
2. Let all dynamical variables (including the Hamiltonian) become operators through their dependence on the conjugate variables
   \begin{align*}
       f(q_{i},p_{i},t)\rightarrow\hat{f}(\hat{Q}_{i},\hat{P}_{i},t)
   \end{align*}
3. Replace the poisson brackets with $\frac{1}{i\hbar}$ times the commutator
   \begin{align*}
       \{f,g\}\rightarrow\frac{1}{i\hbar}[\hat{f},\hat{g}]
   \end{align*}

Do these conditions enforce the fact that $\langle\hat{A}\rangle$ will correspond to the classically measured value? If so, is there a way to mathematically show this? If not, is there an extra condition we must add to enforce this fact

Comment: Well, OP's quantization step 2 is an under-specified non-unique procedure as written (v5). How should the $\hat{Q}$s and $\hat{P}$s be ordered? Which operator ordering should be used? Hence the title question is ill-defined.